# Can you write a review for a game you don't own?

Tags: steam

Can you write a review for a game you don't own in your Steam library?

I recently asked a refund for a game I played less than 2 hours. I really disliked it and I feel I should write a review to explain to other Steam's users. Am I in a hurry to write it before the game is removed from my Steam library?..

This question can be relevant too for a player that owns a game outside their Steam library but would like to write a review on the platform.

Comment: I assume you are asking if you are capable of doing it once the game is removed from your library as supposed to a moral, ethical or legal dilemma? When I say the title I expected something different.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If the Steam game isn't in your Steam account library, you can't write a review for it, period.

> Q. Do I need to have purchased a game in order to write a review of it?
>
> A. Purchase is not required. You **may write a review for any product in your Steam account**. Whether you registered a Steam key obtained elsewhere, or played a free game, you will be able to write a review for that product. Your playtime in that game or time in that software title will appear next to your review.

[Source](http://store.steampowered.com/reviews/)

Comment: Plus you need to have played the game for atleast 5 mins. I'm not sure if this rule only exists for free to play games.

Comment: Are you sure this applies to games that have been refunded?

Answer (score -4):

No, you can't write a review if the game isn't in your library, however if you trade for Steam Trading cards from a game you don't own, you can still craft the badges associated to that game.

Comment: Just saying it. Its only extra info...

Comment: If this doesn't answer the question, then this info would be better as a comment than as an answer to the question. The downvotes are because your "answer" didn't answer the question -- regardless of how helpful or not helpful it is.